# How should one retrieve the word under cursor, of current active window?

Tags: c++, winapi

How could I retrieve the word under the cursor, on the currently active window? My thought was to use `GetCursorPos()` and `WindowFromPoint()` to get the handle, and do something, but how?

Imagine a dictionary app, which reads the text under the cursor, and give an explanation of its meaning.

**EDIT**

I end up use the dll from stardict, with its API hooks on text drawing.

Comment: "Of any window" is impossible. You need to know the window class and what messages it will respond to. Particularly something like a PDF viewer isn't going to be able to give you that information.

Comment: @MarkRansom you're right, I modified the question now; Is there a way that works on most cases?

Comment: @MarkRansom: A decent PDF viewer actually is likely to give up that information

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to know the API needed for this; it's not obvious. You're looking for MSAA, [Microsoft Active Accessibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373592(v=vs.85).aspx)

In short, you'll write an MSAA client. By calling `AccessibleObjectFromPoint` you get an `IAccessible` pointer. This pointer gives access to the properties of the object at the specified point.

Comment: It worked, but it reads everything (e.g all text in notepad) , not a single word, maybe I've missed some points

Comment: It's up to each MSAA server to decide what's returned. Notepad is a simple app, just a single edit control. It probably doesn't implement its own `IAccessible` but reuses the edit control one.

Comment: @warl0ck When you find a solution that fits your needs, if someone else hasn't already posted the code to do it, perhaps you could? It'd be beneficial to the community as a whole.

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for is not trivial to implement.

Once you have determined which window is under the cursor (don't forget that you also need to use `ChildWindowFromPoint()` to drill down through nested windows), you can use `GetClassName()` to figure out what type of window it is.

For a standard `RICHEDIT` window, you can translate the screen-absolute cursor coordinates into client-relative coordinates within the window using `MapWindowPoints()` and then use the `EM_FINDWORDBREAK`, `EM_EXSETSEL`, and `EM_GETSELTEXT` messages to locate, highlight, and copy the word at the cursor coordinates.

For a standard `EDIT` window, once you have translated the coordinates, you can use the `EM_CHARFROMPOS` message to locate the character offset nearest the cursor coordinates, then use the `EM_GETTEXT` message for a single-line window, or the `EM_LINEFROMCHAR` and `EM_GETLINE` messages for a multi-line window (use `GetWindowLong(GWL_STYLE)` to test for the `ES_MULTILINE` style), to retreive the window's text, and then you would have to manually parse the text surrounding the character offset.

For other types of windows, especially custom controls, you have to do a lot more work, if it is even possible to get access to the window's text at all.  Some windows respond to `WM_GETTEXT` messages and/or `GetWidnowText()`, while others do not.

Comment: Indeed it's not trivial. That's why you use MSAA or UIAutomation.